# How to change default 'page' Directory name or Location in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to clean up project structure by moving 'Page' directory form root location to some internal folder's like client or frontend etc. Is there way to do it? and can I move css and images folder as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the `pages` directory is concerned, it's not configurable yet but it has been discussed so the feature might be available some time in the future: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/936

Images are usually best kept in the `static` folder, eg. `/static/img/favicon.png`, if you move your images somewhere you'll lose Next.js feature of automatically setting up static files serving under `/static/*`.

Regarding CSS however, you're free to move these files under any folder you want because you have to import them in your code yourself: https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css

Comment: I addition..  location of directory could be changed. more details here https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2202#issuecomment-307145608